How to label a dbt project so that I can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA for all jobs created by this project?

dbt-core: 1.8.0
dbt-bigquery: 1.8.1

I have a dbt-core project that includes 2 tables (1 incremental, 1 that aggregates the incremental table).
Since dbt only logs the direct *.sql files but not the incremental macro magic with the MERGE statements the logged bytes_billed in the /target/run_results.json are missing the majority of the costs when you run your project.
To solve this issue I need a way to get all jobs that are created when I run my dbt project.
dbt_project.yml:
models:
  dbt_tracking:
    near_realtime:
      +tags: near_realtime
      +labels:
        source: dbt_near_realtime
      +materialized: table

config for the models/near_realtime/stg_near_realtime_events.sql file:
{{
    config(
        labels={"task_id": "near_realtime"},
        materialized="incremental",
        incremental_strategy="merge",
        on_schema_change="append_new_columns",
        partition_by={
            "field": "derived_tstamp",
            "data_type": "timestamp",
            "granularity": "hour",
        },
        partition_expiration_days=1,
        cluster_by=["event_name"],
    )
}}

config for the models/near_realtime/int_near_realtime_aggs.sql file:
{{
    config(
        labels = {"task_id": "near_realtime"},
    )
}}

execution command:
dbt run --select tag:near_realtime

but when I search for my label in the
`my_project_id.region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER`

the only label.key I get via:
select distinct
  labels[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].key
from
  `my_project_id.region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_USER`
where
  timestamp_trunc(creation_time, day) = timestamp(current_date())

is this:
dbt_invocation_id

How can I query the jobs for my query so that I can see which total_bytes_billed my project run in dbt created for cost calculations?

Add this to your dbt_profile.yml:
query-comment:
  job-label: True
  comment: "{{ var('query_label', 'dbt_run') }}"

Then you can set a query label via:
dbt run --select tag:my_tag --vars '{"query_label": "here_is_my_label"}'

You can then analyse the total_bytes_billed per job query label in BQ via:
with
  dbt_cloud_logs as (
      select
          datetime(creation_time, "Europe/Berlin")                                                                              as creation_time
        , (select unnested_labels.value from unnest(labels) as unnested_labels where unnested_labels.key = "dbt_invocation_id") as dbt_invocation_id
        , (select unnested_labels.value from unnest(labels) as unnested_labels where unnested_labels.key = "query_comment")     as dbt_query_label
        , total_bytes_billed
      from
          `region-eu.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS`
      where
          1=1
      and user_email                          = "your_service_account_or_email_adress"
      and timestamp_trunc(creation_time, day, "Europe/Berlin") >= timestamp("when_did_you_implement_job_query_labels?", "Europe/Berlin")
)


select
    *
from
    dbt_cloud_logs
where
    1=1
and dbt_query_label is not null
and dbt_invocation_id is not null
order by
    dbt_query_label
  , creation_time desc

